# How to display captured image with HTML2canvas in another div

Tags: javascript, html, web, html2canvas

Currently when i press the button, the captured image will be displayed in the body of the HTML. But how do I make it that the captured image will only be displayed in another div with the id of "image". I tried using document.getElementById("image").appendChild(canvas) but it did not work. 
Need to do this as I'm planning to hide the element first by using getElementById("image").="none" and it'll only appear after a click of a button.

HTML code:

```
    <div>
       <table id="capture">                 
                <tr id="date" class="selected">
                   <th>Date</th>
                   <th>11/5</th>                  
                   <th>12/5</th>
                   <th>13/5</th>
                   <th>14/5</th>
                   <th>15/5</th>
                   <th>16/5</th>
                   <th>17/5</th>

                </tr>
                <tr class="selected">
                    <th>Day</th>                  
                    <th>Mon</th>
                    <th>Tue</th>
                    <th>Wed</th>
                    <th>Thu</th>
                    <th>Fri</th>
                    <th>Sat</th>
                    <th>Sun</th>
                </tr>           
            </table>

          <input type="button" value="Last Week's Dosage History" class="submitonclick="showlastweek()"/> 
            <button type="button" class="submit" onclick="capture1()">Capture<small></small></button>
    </div> 

    <div id="image">
    //image to be placed here
    </div>
```

Js code:

```
function capture1(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
}
```

Comment: It works just fine exactly with code provided. Make sure you are even including html2canvas properly and on every activation you can see it working in your console.log

Comment: It's because  I'm planning to hide the element first by using getElementById("image").="none" and it'll only appear after a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Tested and working.

`document.getElementById("image").appendChild(canvas);` Works just fine... But `getElementById("image").="none"` means nothing. See below.

```js
function capture1() {
 html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then((canvas) => {
  document.getElementById("image").appendChild(canvas);
 });
}

function showDiv() {
 var hiddenDiv = document.querySelector("#image");
 hiddenDiv.style.display = hiddenDiv.style.display === "none" ? "" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div>
      <table id="capture">
        <tr id="date" class="selected">
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>11/5</th>
          <th>12/5</th>
          <th>13/5</th>
          <th>14/5</th>
          <th>15/5</th>
          <th>16/5</th>
          <th>17/5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="selected">
          <th>Day</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tue</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thu</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Sun</th>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <input type="button" value="Last Week's Dosage History"
      class="submit" onclick="showlastweek()"/>
      <button type="button" class="submit" onclick="capture1()">
        Capture<small></small>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="image" style="display: none;">
      //image to be placed here
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />

    <button type="button" class="submit" onclick="showDiv()">
      Toggle div display
    </button>
```